# Dynamically change a column's editable property with select box

Tags: jqgrid

I am using form editing.  I would like to disable certain fields in my add and edit forms based on the selection from a drop down box.  What event is best to use to trigger this?  I have attempted using dataEvents:

```
{    name:'type_cd', 
     edittype:'select', 
     editoptions:{
        dataUrl:'functions.php',
            dataEvents:[{
                type:'change',
                fn: function(e){
                    $(this).setColProp('cntrct_id',{
                         editoptions:{editable:false}
                    });
            } 
       }]                        
    } 
},
```

This has no visible effect on my form fields, but I know that it's being reached because I can get an alert message from it if I put one in.

**EDIT**

If I submit the form, the next time I open it, the column that was set to editable:false will not appear.  This is a step in the right direction, BUT I want it to *immediately* be uneditable.  Really, I would like it to be visible, but disabled (i.e. disabled:true)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all `dataEvents` allows you to register callbacks on elements of edit elements. Inside of callbacks `this` will be initialized to the DOM element which will be bound. So `$(this)` inside of `change` handler it will be wrapper on `<select>` element and not on the grid. The usage of `$(this).setColProp` will be incorrect.

To disable some input field in Add/Edit form you can use the fact that all input elements get the same `id` like the value of `name` property on the corresponding column in `colModel`. So if you need to disable input of `cntrct_id` you can set `disabled` property to `true` on the element with `id="cntrct_id"`

```js
{
     name: 'type_cd', 
     edittype: 'select', 
     editoptions: {
        dataUrl: 'functions.php',
        dataEvents: [{
            type: 'change',
            fn: function (e) {
                // disable input/select field for column 'cntrct_id'
                // in the edit form
                $("#cntrct_id").prop("disabled", true);
            } 
       }]                        
    } 
}
```

It's important to understand that `editoptions` will be used for any existing editing modes (form editing, inline editing and cell editing). If you want to write the code of `dataEvents` which supports all editing modes you have to detect editing mode and use a little other ids of editing fields. The code (not tested) can be about as below

```js
{
     name: 'type_cd', 
     edittype: 'select', 
     editoptions: {
        dataUrl: 'functions.php',
        dataEvents: [{
            type: 'change',
            fn: function (e) {
                var $this = $(e.target), $td, rowid;
                // disable input/select field for column 'cntrct_id'
                if ($this.hasClass("FormElement")) {
                    // form editing
                    $("#cntrct_id").prop("disabled", true);
                } else {
                    $td = $this.closest("td");
                    if ($td.hasClass("edit-cell") {
                        // cell editing
                        // we don't need to disable $("#cntrct_id")
                        // because ONLY ONE CELL are edited in cell editing mode
                    } else {
                        // inline editing
                        rowid = $td.closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
                        if (rowid) {
                            $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(rowid) + "_cntrct_id")
                                .prop("disabled", true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
       }]                        
    } 
}
```

The last remark. If you still use old version of jQuery (before jQuery 1.6) which don't support [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method you have to use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead.

Comment: The great thing about your answers, Oleg, is that you don't just tell the solution, you explain the theory behind it.  You're awesome.

Comment: @MattWall: You are welcome! I'm glad that you like my style answering on questions. I think that *understanding* the problem is even more important as the solution of the problem itself.

Comment: I also like Oleg's way of answering, When I started using jqgrid I got solution for most of my jqgrid related issues from Oleg's answers. Thank you Oleg

Comment: @Kris: Thanks Kris! I'm glad that I could help you too. You are welcome!

Answer (score -1):

@Oleg: This is working(could get the alert messages) but its not disabling the field.
Should the form field require any special values?

Comment: This isn't an answer.  Try contributing to the site, and  that will give you enough reputation to comment on other people's answers.

Comment: @Pravish Jayasundar, Better yet, ask a new question

Comment: I could not add comments to the above question so I had to posted as an answer