# jqgrid overwrite id and name properties for text box

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

When I am editing with inline editing of jqGrid. jqGrid will generate textboxes, with the id formatted as "rowid_columnid", where rowid is the rowid, and columnid is the id of the column.
But the name property is just the column id.
what is the easiest way to overwrite the name property of the generated textbox?
I want to name property to be "columnid[rowid]"

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't overwrite the process of id generation. In some situations, like inside of `dataInit` or inside of `dataEvents` callbacks, it's enough to detect in which editing mode the callback works and just to use the corresponding id construct. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5257794/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14964923/315935) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4480184/315935).