# JQGRID - How to Send/Read Values from Different Columns in Inline / Form edit?

Tags: jqgrid

I have 3 checkbox columns with corresponding date column. So what I am trying to achieve is when user clicks on checkbox during inline-edit and hits enter, today's date will be sent set as the value for another cell in a specified column. How to achieve? I recieved prior direction from OLEG on doing this with on form-edit but I would like to do this during inline edit instead. I have both enabled but only checkmarks will be editable during inline edit. I have all other fields disabled but the checkboxes columns. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE** Okay so I solved with the below code. Thanks Oleg for the help.

Current Date Function:

```
var date = new Date(Date.now());
console.log(todayDate(date));
function todayDate(date){
return (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
    }
```

Check Column Code:

```
        { name: "devc", index: "devc",width: 25, align: "right", formatter: "checkbox", 
    editable: true, edittype: "checkbox",editoptions: {value: "Yes:No",defaultValue: "No",
dataEvents: [{type: "change", fn: function (e) {var $this = $(e.target), columnName = "devdate", rowid, cellId;
                                if ($this.hasClass("FormElement")) {
                                    // form editing
                                    cellId = columnName;
                                } else if ($this.closest("td").hasClass("edit-cell")) {
                                    // cell editing
                                    return; // no other editing field exist - nothing to do
                                } else {
                                    // inline editing
                                    rowid = $this.closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
                                    cellId = rowid + "_" + columnName;
                                }
                                $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(cellId)).val($this.is(":checked") ?
                                    (todayDate(date)) : "");} }]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to address *another editing field* inside of some event handler defined in `dataEvents` you need uses the corresponding name conversion for ids used by different editing mode.

Form editing creates editing elements with `id` attribute the same as the `name` property in `colModel`.  Inline editing allows to edit *multiple* rows at the same time. So it uses another rule for building id values: the rowid value will be appended by `_` and then appended with the value of `name` property in `colModel`. During cell editing jqGrid allows to edit *one cell* only. So accessing of *another* editing field inside of some event handler defined in `dataEvents` have no sense.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14964923/315935) provide an example of detection of editing mode inside of event handler of `dataEvents`.

Let us you have column `{ name: "appc", formatter: "checkbox", editable: true, edittype: "checkbox", ...}` and you need to define `change` event handler for the column. Let us you have another text column `{ name: "appdate", editable: true, ...}` and you want change the value of the the edit field of `appdate` column on checking/unchecking of the checkbox in `appc` column. In the case you can do the following:

```js
{ name: "appdate", editable: true, ...},
{ name: "appc", formatter: "checkbox", editable: true, edittype: "checkbox",
    editoptions: {
        dataEvents: [{
            type: "change",
            fn: function (e) {
                var $this = $(e.target), columnName = "appdate", rowid, cellId;
                if ($this.hasClass("FormElement")) {
                    // form editing
                    cellId = columnName;
                } else if ($this.closest("td").hasClass("edit-cell")) {
                    // cell editing
                    return; // no other editing field exist - nothing to do
                } else {
                    // inline editing
                    rowid = $this.closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
                    cellId = rowid + "_" + columnName;
                }

                // set the value of another edit field
                // we use below $.jgrid.jqID(cellId) instead of cellId
                // only to be sure that the next line work correctly
                // even in case of columnName contains special meta-charackters
                // like space or !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~
                $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(cellId)).val($this.is(":checked") ?
                    "CheckedText": "UncheckedText");
            } 
        }]
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**: One can modify the code from your question to the following:

```js
var date = new Date(Date.now()),
    todayDate = function (date) {
        return (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() +
            "/" + date.getFullYear();
    },
    checkBoxChange = function (e) {
        var $this = $(e.target), columnName = e.data.dateColumn,
            rowid, cellId;

        if ($this.hasClass("FormElement")) {
            // form editing
            cellId = columnName;
        } else if ($this.closest("td").hasClass("edit-cell")) {
            // cell editing
            return; // no other editing field exist - nothing to do
        } else {
            // inline editing
            rowid = $this.closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
            cellId = rowid + "_" + columnName;
        }
        $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(cellId)).val($this.is(":checked") ?
            (todayDate(date)) : "");
    };

...
...
{ name: "appdate", editable: true, ...},
{ name: "appc", formatter: "checkbox", editable: true,
    edittype: "checkbox",
    editoptions: {
        dataEvents: [{
            type: "change",
            data:  { dateColumn: "appdate" },
            fn: checkBoxChange
        }]
    }},
{ name: "devdate", editable: true, ...},
{ name: "devc", formatter: "checkbox", editable: true,
    edittype: "checkbox",
    editoptions: {
        dataEvents: [{
            type: "change",
            data:  { dateColumn: "devdate" },
            fn: checkBoxChange
        }]
    }}
```

One can see that we use `data:  { dateColumn: "devdate" }` or `data:  { dateColumn: "appdate" }` as additional property of `dataEvents` items. The event handler `checkBoxChange` used in `fn: checkBoxChange` can access the `data` by usage `e.data.dateColumn`. In the way one can easy share the same event handler for multiple columns.

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: You don't wrote clear enough what you want to write in the field. *You can write the value which you need.* In the text of the question you wrote that you what to set current date only if some field is empty. Probably you need to test `$("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(cellId)).val()` and if it's non-empty and the checkbox are set then you can set the current date. The rule is that the question have some value if it's not very specific. I don't believe that some other person will need to set date based on some checkbox, but I believe that one could access (get/set) *another* editing field

Comment: I'll figure out how to adjust the value. Thanks for you guidance.

Comment: Minor question: How to address changing multiple columns?

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Do you want to use the same `fn` in multiple columns? Then you need just define the event handler function not as anonymous function.

Comment: I mean that the checkmark event changes the value in 3 columns not just 1. Could you help?

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: If I correctly understand your problem you can follow **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: I see. So if I woud use `data:  { dateColumn: "appdate", "otherColumn","yetotherColumn"},` would this change all these columns together?Because this is what I seek.

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: Why you not just describe **exactly** what you want? The usage of `data: { dateColumn: "appdate", "otherColumn","yetotherColumn"},` is not possible because it's syntax error. I understood you so that you have 6 columns: 3 dates and 3 checkboxs. I posted the code with 2+2 columns instead of 3+3. **Could you describe exactly your problem?** Which columns of which type you have, why you can't use the existing solution, what you really need to implement?

Comment: Say that `checkBoxChange`  changes values of 2+ other columns at the same time, to address change value of multiple column . I want `dateColumn`  to contain data for multiple columns so that when checkbox is checked multiple columns are changed at once. Possible?

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: You need just uses the selector `$("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(cellId1) + ",#" + $.jgrid.jqID(cellId2) + ",#" + $.jgrid.jqID(cellId3))` instead of `$("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(cellId))` in the last line which set `val`.

Comment: You have been really helpful. Would this be the same for `edittype:'select'`? I've tried with select and it does not fire.